# How to get an integer value using get() in views.py?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create an object in my views.py that is an integer from models.py. Usually we have lists in the models.py objects, but in this case it is just a single number.

```
def answer(request, level_id):
    o = Level.objects.get(id=level_id)
    correct = o.answers.filter(value__iexact=guess).exists() <--- working boolean function
    points = o.points.get('points')
    values = { 'score':points }
    return render_to_response('game.html', values)
```

This gives us an error:

> Int has no attribute get.

We are trying to create the points variable to contain the number of points from our models.py:

```
class Level(models.Model):
    points = models.IntegerField("Point Value",default=1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have your Level object, you can just call `o.points` to get the value of the points attribute, you don't need to call `o.points.get('points')`.

As `o.points` is an integer, you're seeing this error because integers do not have a `.get` method.

Comment: Our error is gone. That is great. But our template engine won't print {{score}}

Comment: Yes it does. We added a value in admin. Plus gave it a default value of 1, as is written in the code above.
I actually was able to display the o.points after putting inside another object in my Level view. But I can't get the same variable to display in my Game view.

Comment: That sounds like a different question, which would require different background to answer.